# dplyr & groups : what is the difference between keep and ungroup or directly drop?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, sum, dataset

I need to sum the observations referred to the same individual without having a unique identification  code/row for them .

This is a sample of the dataset

```
> head(dataset, 20)
   nquest nord tpens
1     173    1  1800
2     633    1   300
3     633    1   600
4     923    1   500
5    2886    1  1211
6    2886    2  2100
7    5416    1   700
8    7886    1  1800
9    7886    1   200
10  20297    1  1200
11  20711    2  2000
12  22169    1   600
13  22169    1   280
14  22173    2  1000
15  22276    1  1200
16  22286    1   850
17  22286    2   650
18  22657    1  1400
19  22657    2  1500
20  23490    1  1400
```

The variables are:

1. `nquest` = is the code of the family to which the individual belong
2. `nord` = is the position of the individual in the family ( 1=husband, 2=wife, 3= son, etc..)
3. `tpens` = is the wage that each one of them earn

I need to sum the values of the wage that are referred to the same individual. For example

[image: Dataset]

As you can see, these values of `tpens` are referred to the same individual because not only `nquest` is the same ( family code) , but also `nord`.

I've tried to do it in 2 ways ( following some suggestions )

First way

```
new_dataset <- dataset %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>% 
  summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .groups = 'drop')
```

Second way

```
new_dataset <- dataset %>%   
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%   
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>%    
  summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .groups = 'keep') %>% 
  ungroup
```

Are they right?
Can anyone explain me the difference between computing the sum with `keep` groups and then `ungroup` and instead `drop` the groups directly ??

I'm a bit confused because I do not understand this thing: if I make the sum of the values that correspond to each individual, I should not have groups at the end of the process... but just 1 indvidual per rows ( Am I wrong?). If I merge this dataset with another one matching by `nquest` and `nord` ( hence for each person ), I get instead `# A tibble: 6 x 41 # Groups: nquest, nord [6]`.

How is that possible?

Comment: The `.groups` argument only affects the grouping structure of the result, so `.groups = 'keep'` keeps the grouping in `group_by` while `.groups = 'drop'` will ungroup the result. It will not have any effects on how the function in `summarise` is executed.

Comment: To check if the outputs are the same, you can use `identical`. i.e. `identical(df1, df2)`.

Comment: hi @benson23 thank for the answer. I do not understand this thing: if I make the sum of the values that correspond to each individual, i should not have groups at the end of the process... but just 1 indvidual per rows ( Am I wrong?) . I get instead ` # A tibble: 6 x 41 # Groups:   nquest, nord [6] `

Comment: The difference is (at least for me) that you can avoid() the final ungroup() in version 2. With dplyr >= 1.0.0 now there is another way like : `df %>%   
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%   
  summarize(tpens = sum(tpens), .by=c(nquest, nord))` . Finally all 3 do the same: group - do something - and ungroup!

Comment: For your understanding: It is not important in this case what you see. The ungrouped data has 20 rows the grouped data has 17 rows. But the main thing is that your operations after grouping will affect only inside groups. This is sometimes what you want, but sometime you want to apply your function to the whole data frame and not only to the groups. For example `arrange` -> unfortunately also a special issue. If you want to arrange within groups after grouping you have to : `arrange(.by_group = TRUE)`. So and the next step will be learing about `group_modify` `group_walk` and `group_map`. :-)

Comment: hi @TarJae if I do not specify group = `keep` or `drop` I get a warning message

Comment: This is ok. It is just a Warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between using `.groups = 'keep'` and `.groups = 'drop'` lies in the state of the `tibble` after these functions. If you use `.groups = 'keep'`, the `tibble` will be grouped until you run `ungroup()`. However, if you use `.groups = 'drop'`, the `tibble` will no longer be grouped after you run `summarize`. To learn more, check out the "Verbs" section of the documentation [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html?q=.groups%20=%20%22keep%22#summarise).

Take this example:

```
data("iris")
library(dplyr)

## Let's try "keep"
grouped <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%\
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "keep")
grouped

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    count
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 setosa        50
#> 2 versicolor    50
#> 3 virginica     50

grouped %>% group_data()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Species          .rows
#>   <fct>      <list<int>>
#> 1 setosa             [1]
#> 2 versicolor         [1]
#> 3 virginica          [1]

## Now, let's try "drop"
ungrouped <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%\
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "keep")
ungrouped

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    count
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 setosa        50
#> 2 versicolor    50
#> 3 virginica     50

ungrouped %>% group_data()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>         .rows
#>   <list<int>>
#> 1         [3]
```

The key difference is these outputs is the grouping - if we do not `ungroup()` or use `.groups = 'drop'`, the output remains grouped. This means that future operations will treat this `tibble` as grouped, which could create unintended consequences.

If you only need to use grouping for one function, try the `.by` parameter. Learn more [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_by.html?q=.by#using-by). This way instead of having to remember to use `.groups = 'drop'` or `ungroup()`, you can just write:

```
iris %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .by = Species)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Species    count
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 setosa        50
#> 2 versicolor    50
#> 3 virginica     50
```

Learn more about grouped data [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html#group_by).